# Array[] imprimir

Tags: java, string, imprimir

tengo un problema al imprimir un String[] que se encuentra dentro de un ArrayList de objetos al imprimir algunos imprime como null.

```
Pasaporte - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
5
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Antecentes penales Apostillados - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
6
Votantes: [
ramses, antonieta, marlyn, weber, simon, andres, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
```

Mas o menos asi me salen unos si imprime su contenidos y otros no.

Asi lo mando a imprimir en el main

```
for(int i=0; i<p.listCanc.size();i++){
    MetodosListCanc.impObj(p.listCanc.get(i));
}
```

ya he probado de varias manera y me sigue dando error aca dejo el metodo que imprime

```
public static void impObj(InfCanc i){
    System.out.println(i.getName());
    System.out.println(i.getLoc());
    System.out.println(i.getVal());
    System.out.println("Votantes: [");
    String sl []=i.getVotantes();
    for(int j=0; j<20;j++){
        System.out.print(sl[j]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    System.out.println("------------");
}
/*public static void impObj(int i){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getLoc());
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getVal());
    System.out.println("Votantes: "+Arrays.toString(list.get(i).getVotantes()));
    System.out.println("------------");
}*/
```

de ambas formas me da el mismo error de impresión con algunos objetos.

Answer (score 2):

a lo que entiendo de tu pregunta y la estructura de los objetos, tu problema parece ser la condición de parada del ciclo, por acá:

```
 for(int j=0; j<20;j++)
```

En el método *impObj*, prueba cambiar `j<20` por `j<sl.length()`, length te da el tamaño del arreglo. Y además valida que el campo no sea null, dentro del ciclo coloca:

```
if(sl[j] != null)
    System.out.print(sl[j]+", ");
```

Quedaría algo como:

```
public static void impObj(InfCanc i){
    System.out.println(i.getName());
    System.out.println(i.getLoc());
    System.out.println(i.getVal());
    System.out.println("Votantes: [");
    String sl []=i.getVotantes();
    for(int j=0; j<sl.length();j++){
        if(sl[j] != null)
            System.out.print(sl[j]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    System.out.println("------------");
}
```